# Cannot remove image using unlink, are my permissions wrong?

Tags: php, file-io, unlink

I'm trying to use unlink to delete pictures from deleted comments but it's simply not working. The comment from the database gets deleted but the actual picture doesn't. What am I doing wrong? The folder permissions are 755 and the image permissions are 644.

```
if (loggedin()) {
    $dblink = mysqli_connect($DBhostname, $DBusername, $DBpassword, $DBname);
    if (!$dblink) {die("Connection error (".mysqli_connect_errno.") " . mysqli_connect_error());}

    $commentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dblink, $_GET['c']);

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id='$commentid' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($dblink, $qry) or die(mysqli_error($dblink));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $commenter = $row["commenter"];
        $thereisimg = $row["thereisimg"];
        $imgtype = $row["imgtype"];

        // if logged in email = email of commenter
        if ($_SESSION["logged-in"] == $commenter) {

            // delete comment
            $qry = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id=$commentid";
            $result = mysqli_query($dblink, $qry) or die(mysqli_error($dblink));

            // if image, delete image
            if ($thereisimg) {
                // delete image
                $imglink = "/imgs/commentpics/".$commentid.".".$imgtype;
                echo $imglink;
                unlink($imglink);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The path is wrong - check the difference between relative and absolute paths.

Comment: I tried both /imgs/ and imgs/ and neither worked.

Comment: It's not about doing random things - just read about it somewhere and specify the proper path. Another keyword to examine: current working directory

Comment: What would I change the path to then?

Comment: The script is being run from / . The image is in imgs/commentpics/xx.xxx . The path should work shouldn't it?

Comment: "The script is being run from /" --- it's highly unlikely. If instead of arguing you spent time by googling you would find http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: I just ran exif_imagetype($imglink) where $imglink = "imgs/commentpics/xx.xxx" and it worked. So the path is correct, that's not the issue.

Comment: Can you get the error from unlink(), or use strace() on the process to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose, try one of the following:

1. Add an error handler to the PHP code to capture the error
2. Use strace to trace the process and get the exact result of the unlink() system call

Here's a document for (1): http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp.

To do 2:

```
strace -e unlink php myScript.php
```

That assumes the script can be run directly from the command line.

**Setting an Error Handler**

```
<?php

function my_error_handler($error_level,$error_message,
$error_file,$error_line,$error_context) 
{
        echo $error_message;
}

set_error_handler("my_error_handler");
```